# How to save and send as excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

In my code im saving my excel sheet as pdf and attaching it to an email. What changes do i need to make so that instead of exporting it as a pdf file, it will save and send as a new excel sheet?
By the way, the code for pdf works.

Thanks

```
Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.ClearContents
Set myRange = Application.Union(Range("A1:E3"), Range("A5:E5"), Range("A8:E17"), Range("A19:E48"), Range("A49:E77"))
myRange.Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

'Create the PDF
Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating
```

Comment: Hi @theudster, welcome to SO. Please read [ask] to see how you can improve your question, and with that attract better answers. For starters show us your code, so we can help you improve on that.

Comment: a quick search an this is the top post on Google: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm

Comment: Not so hard to do. Right now I am not to post the answer. If you do not find your solution then knock me after two days.