# Saving as excel macro-single sheet

Tags: excel, vba, save

I have a worksheet which i export to pdf and would like to save part of it as excel. When i use the code to save the excel sheet, it just generates the sheet, without saving it

thanks for the help

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
 With Worksheets("Sheet1")
 .SaveAs "C:\Users\" & .Sheet(1).Name
 .Sheets(1).Name
 .Close0
```

Comment: are you copying to a new workbook? or you want to save `sheet1` as a new workbook?

Comment: i want to save sheet 1 as a new workbook

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50290810/4961700

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save and send as excel macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290810/how-to-save-and-send-as-excel-macro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should solve it

```
Sub CopySht_as_NewWrkBook()

Dim strFileName As String

'Copy sheet as a new workbook
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy

'this creates the "Save as". Change sheets as to your sheet. The new 
'workbook is now the active one
strFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("C:\Users\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Name & ".xls")
If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFileName

'Change "False" to "True" as you like if you wanna have prompt at the end
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Hope this nudges you in the right direction

**EDIT**
Save file without any prompts remove `Application.GetSaveAs...` like so:

```
Sub CopySht_as_NewWrkBook()

Dim strFileName As String

'Copy sheet as a new workbook
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy

'this creates the "Save as". Change sheets as to your sheet. The new 
'workbook is now the active one
strFileName = "C:\Users\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Name & ".xls"
If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFileName

'Change "False" to "True" as you like if you wanna have prompt at the end
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, this helps, but it opens a prompt as to where to save it, I want it to go to a set destination

Comment: added an extra example, hope that gives you ur answer

Comment: Thanks, but it just saves on the desktop as opposed to my destination folders

Comment: well thats what you put in your Q. Just add your folder after `"C:Users\your_folder_and\so_on\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Name & ".xls"`